# How to correctly type the `animated` fn in a typed custom react hook?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-spring

I am battling with using `react-spring` (it's awesome) in a typescript project, with `noImplicitAny` turned on. I need to export the animated function from react-spring as part of my custom hook. But I can't figure out how to type it correctly.

Here is my attempt at it...

---

```
/* Custom react hook - useAnimation.js */

import {
  ForwardRefExoticComponent,
  ComponentPropsWithRef,
  ReactType,
} from 'react';
import { useSpring, animated, AnimatedValue } from 'react-spring';

interface UseAnimationReturnTypes {
  /* Typing this animated fn (1) */
  animated<T extends ReactType>(
    comp: T
  ): ForwardRefExoticComponent<ComponentPropsWithRef<T>>;
  fadeIn: AnimatedValue<{}>;
}

const useAnimation = (): UseAnimationReturnTypes => {
  const fadedAnim = useSpring({
    opacity: 1,
    transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)',
    from: {
      opacity: 0,
      transform: 'translate3d(0, -0.25rem, 0)',
    },
  });

  return {
    animated,
    fadeIn: fadedAnim,
  };
};

export default useAnimation;
```

**(1)** Tried looking through the signature of animated in react-spring, and thought I would get away with that typing (TypeScript newbie btw).

[image: Screenshot showing <code>animated</code>'s type definitions with intelli sense]

*Above* Intelli sense type definitions for `animated`

---

On using it inside a component like this..

```
/* My Component Welcome.js */

import React from 'react';
/* I do not want to import animated directly (3) */
// import { animated } from 'react-spring'

import useAnimation from './animations/useAnimation';

const Welcome = (): JSX.Element => {
  /* I need to extract it from the hook (4) */
  const { fadeIn, animated } = useAnimation();
  return (
    { /* animated.div throws the type error (2) */ }
    <animated.div className="display-message" style={fadeIn}>
      <h1 className="title">Hello</h1>
      <hr />
      <div className="message">
        <p>
          Your are In!
          <strong> &nbsp; Welcome</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </animated.div>
  );
};
```

**(2)** Typescript complains at `animated.div` with the following error!

> `Property 'div' does not exist on type '<T extends ElementType<any>>(comp: T) => ForwardRefExoticComponent<ComponentPropsWithRef<T>>'.ts(2339)`

---

**`#PS`** I could import `animated` directly from `react-spring` and use it within my component **(3)** and it works that way, but I would prefer to separate all spring related code into that custom hook and import it from there instead **(4)**.

What is the correct/most appropriate way to define types for animated? **(1)**. Are there any exported types that I am missing in `react-spring`? Thank you.

Comment: is should be possible to `import {animated as animatedType} from {react-spring/types}` (or something similar to reach https://github.com/react-spring/react-spring/blob/5ac0ad2eda7c055ac54beaacf55c1be4a8b437a0/types/renderprops-universal.d.ts#L127 in the distributed package)

Comment: @Aprillion, TypeScript cannot resolve the module at 'react-spring/types'. I double checked in the npm directory(running react-spring v. `^8.0.19`) and there is neither a file nor folder named `types`. I had however tried the approach linked but TypeScript complained about using a value as a type!

Comment: the types must be available *somewhere™* for IntelliJ to be able to find them ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How about `AnimatedComponent<ComponentPropsWithRef<T>>`. I use this for all my typing of `animated` output.